# How do i commit from the Team explorer window in VS2017?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

Is it possible to commit from the Team Explorer?
I can't see an option to do that.
Here is what my Team Explorer window looks like

[image]

It seems that I can push, but I am used to using SourceTree where I can Stage,Commit, then push

[image]

[image]

Strangely I am not seeing the push in the repository

Comment: Clicking on the Branches part you can go to Changes, which allows staging and committing, and Sync which allows pushing and pulling

Comment: Thanks. that is the answer "Branches" does not look like it is a link.

Comment: It’s a bit confusing yes. The only hint is the little arrow on the far right, which isn’t enough to explain the user interface.

Comment: care to write up the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Team Explorer view is actually a collection of “tabbed” views. The section with Branches text is actually a drop down, which is only indicated by the small downward arrow on the far right. From there you can switch to Changes, which allows staging and committing, as well as Sync, which allows push and pull.

All these can also be accessed by clicking the home icon above.